# unordered_map insert error C++

Tags: c++, set, unordered-map

I am trying to insert into an unordered_map with a std::set value declared as such:

```
class Database {
...
private:
    struct CountryRCID {
        int RCID;
        int Vote;
    };
    struct comp {
        bool operator() (const CountryRCID& left, const CountryRCID& right) const {
            return left.RCID < right.RCID;
        }
    };
    std::unordered_map<const char*, std::set<CountryRCID, comp> > CNTVotes;
};
```

In the Database constructor I am reading data in from a file and attempting to insert into the unordered_map

```
Database() {
    char CNT[3];
    CountryRCID RCIDVote;
    ... Insert data into CNT and RCIDVote ...
    CNTVotes.insert(std::make_pair(CNT, RCIDVote));
}
```

And I have attempted compiling the code with both:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++0x
```

and

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x
```

But am receiving the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/istream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/fstream:40,
                 from db.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h: In constructor ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = char*, _U2 = Database::CountryRCID, _T1 = const char* const, _T2 = std::set<Database::CountryRCID, Database::comp, std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID> >]’:
db.h:50:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<Database::CountryRCID, Database::comp, std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID> >::set(Database::CountryRCID)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:212: note: candidates are: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(std::initializer_list<_CharT>, const _Compare&, const _Alloc&) [with _Key = Database::CountryRCID, _Compare = Database::comp, _Alloc = std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:199: note:                 std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&&) [with _Key = Database::CountryRCID, _Compare = Database::comp, _Alloc = std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:188: note:                 std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = Database::CountryRCID, _Compare = Database::comp, _Alloc = std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:145: note:                 std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(const _Compare&, const _Alloc&) [with _Key = Database::CountryRCID, _Compare = Database::comp, _Alloc = std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID>]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:136: note:                 std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set() [with _Key = Database::CountryRCID, _Compare = Database::comp, _Alloc = std::allocator<Database::CountryRCID>]
```

I have also tried different insert methods:

```
CNTVotes[CNT] = RCIDVote;
```

and

```
std::pair <const char*, CountryRCID> test (CNT, RCIDVote);
CNTVotes.insert(test);
```

which just results in similar errors

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could help me understand why it is not working and what I could do to make this work.

Thank you.

Comment: Comparator is for keys, not values. Plus you insert a single object rather than a set.. But even if you fix that, it will crash because the way you work with char pointers as keys is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CountryRCID` is a type `struct`, it is not a `std::set` ... you would first need to construct a `std::set` of type `std::set<CountryRCID>` and use that in your arguments to `makePair()` in order to match the template arguments for your `unordered_map`.

I also think the `struct comp` functor is redundant ... just define `operator<()` and `operator==()` for your `CountryRCID` struct.

If you do that, and change the declaration of `CNTVotes` to (BTW, note that I'm borrowing Neil's suggestion to use `std::string` rather than a `const char*` as the key-value ... I think that's a very good idea)

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<CountryRCID> > CNTVotes;
```

then you can do the following:

```
CountryRCID RCIDVote;
//... Insert data into CNT and RCIDVote ...
std::string CNTString(CNT);
std::set<CountryRCID> RCIDVoteSet;  // <== make a std::set of type set<CountryRCID>
RCIDVoteSet.insert(RCIDVote);
CNTVotes.insert(std::make_pair(CNTString, RCIDVoteSet));
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed to do and I appreciate the help with comp as well.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly nothing directly to do with your problem, but maps of char * never really work. Instead of :

```
 std::unordered_map<const char*, std::set<CountryRCID, comp> > CNTVotes;
```

you probably want:

```
 std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<CountryRCID, comp> > CNTVotes;
```

Comment: Assuming there's an appropriate hash specialization for C-strings I can't see why this wouldn't work (although I still agree with using `string`).

Comment: @mark the chars pointed to are const as far as the map is concerned, but maybe not as far as the user is concerned, so they may change it. An unordered_map requires comparison with the original string in order to avoid collisions, so if this can be changed we are in Undefined Behaviour land. Bottom line, map keys should always be values, unless you are very, very sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, I think I will take your suggestion.  It's not a huge project or anything, just for a school assignment but I appreciate good habits.  Thanks Neil.

Comment: To provide additional justification to @Neil's argument, the string pointed to (`CNT`) appears to go out of scope and be destroyed, leaving the `map` to hold a pointer to destroyed memory.

Comment: To say "maps of char * never really work" is ridiculous. Of course they work. You just have to know how to use them. In particular, you need to (depending on your compiler) provide the equal comparator and the hashing function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor to make a set from a single object of the type that goes into that set. You'll need to create a temporary set and add the item to it, then use that to add to the `unordered_map`.

EDIT: Actually since you have an actual object I think you can get away with the `iterator, iterator` constructor like this:

`CNTVotes.insert(std::make_pair(CNT, std::set(&RCIDVote, &RCIDVote + 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

As Jason mentioned, your value in the map is a set rather than a single `CountryRCID` struct.  If you mean to add the `CountryRCID` to the set in the map you probably want something like:

```
typedef std::set<CountryRCID, comp> MySet;
typedef std::unordered_map<const char*, MySet> MyMap;

MyMap::_Pairib ret = CNTVotes.insert(std::make_pair(CNT, MySet()));
ret.first->second.insert(RCIDVote);
```